# IOS7: How to add hyperlinks in a pdf file?

Tags: ios, pdf, hyperlink

I created a pdf file with 5 pages in the iPad's document directory.
Each page has a paragraph describing the page (e.g. "Page1", "Page2", etc.)
The pdf is totally code generated using UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage.

I would like to change the paragraph in an hyperlink targeting another page inside the pdf file (or an external webpage).
So when the pdf is opened in a PDF reader, the user could change page just clicking on the hyperlink.

Is this something possible with the SDK?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See `UIGraphicsSetPDFContextURLForRect`.